# Recursive tesseract command

Tags: bash, batch-processing, tesseract, batch-rename

I have a lot of tif files (1 page = 1 tif file) and I want to convert them into a single, multipaged, big tif, then launch tesseract on it (for ocr) and obtain a pdf as result.

My files are named this way:

```
    $ ls
    115_XRTL_000_001.tif  115_XRTL_000_004.tif  115_XRTL_000_007.tif  115_XRTL_000_010.tif
    115_XRTL_000_002.tif  115_XRTL_000_005.tif  115_XRTL_000_008.tif  115_XRTL_000_011.tif
    115_XRTL_000_003.tif  115_XRTL_000_006.tif  115_XRTL_000_009.tif
```

I use the following code:

```
    for f in *.tif; do base=${f%_*}; tiffcp $base* ../pdfs/$base.tif; tesseract ../pdfs/$base.tif -l fra ../pdfs/$base pdf; rm -v ../pdfs/$base.tif; done
```

It works well except the part with tesseract. It creates a loop and tesseract works endeless on the same big tif file.

log:

```
$ for f in *.tif; do base=${f%_*}; tiffcp $base* ../../pdfs/$base.tif; tesseract ../../pdfs/$base.tif -l fra ../../pdfs/$base pdf; rm -v ../../pdfs/$base.tif; done
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.00.00alpha with Leptonica
Page 1
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 650
OSD: Weak margin (5.97) for 122 blob text block, but using orientation anyway: 0
Page 2
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 329
Page 3
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 346
Error in boxClipToRectangle: box outside rectangle
Error in pixScanForForeground: invalid box
Page 4
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 371
Page 5
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 375
Page 6
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 368
Page 7
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 370
Detected 26 diacritics
Page 8
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 368
Page 9
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 348
Page 10
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 376
Page 11
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 354
'../../pdfs/115_XRTL_000.tif' supprimé
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.00.00alpha with Leptonica
Page 1
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 650
OSD: Weak margin (5.97) for 122 blob text block, but using orientation anyway: 0
Page 2
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 329
Page 3
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 346
Error in boxClipToRectangle: box outside rectangle
Error in pixScanForForeground: invalid box
Page 4
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 371
Page 5
Warning. Invalid resolution 30000 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 375
^C
```

How can I prevent the loop?

Another issue is the tif files are in different folders.

For example, if I take two folders (I have more):

```
$ ls -R
.:
115_XRTL_000  128_XRTL_001

./115_XRTL_000:
115_XRTL_000_001.tif  115_XRTL_000_004.tif  115_XRTL_000_007.tif  115_XRTL_000_010.tif
115_XRTL_000_002.tif  115_XRTL_000_005.tif  115_XRTL_000_008.tif  115_XRTL_000_011.tif
115_XRTL_000_003.tif  115_XRTL_000_006.tif  115_XRTL_000_009.tif

./128_XRTL_001:
128_XRTL_001_001.tif  128_XRTL_001_005.tif  128_XRTL_001_009.tif  128_XRTL_001_013.tif
128_XRTL_001_002.tif  128_XRTL_001_006.tif  128_XRTL_001_010.tif  128_XRTL_001_014.tif
128_XRTL_001_003.tif  128_XRTL_001_007.tif  128_XRTL_001_011.tif
128_XRTL_001_004.tif  128_XRTL_001_008.tif  128_XRTL_001_012.tif
```

I would like to be able to launch a command which will apply recursively to each folder and create a pdf (with ocr) per folder (moved inside a ../pdfs/ folder).

Comment: What do you mean "it creates a loop"? Where in the filetree structure is your script run?

Comment: @Roadowl I launch my command from inside the folder containing the tif files. Tesseract processes the big tif file but at the end start again. I updated my post with the log for more information.